# Web application Streaming Video and drawing over it

Tags: xml, web-applications, drawing, video-streaming, html5-video

I need to create a webpage which streams video from an IP camera. I guess thats simple enough. But next step is, I want to be able to draw polygons[rectangles] over the video streaming and based on the polygon drawn I need to save the coordinates of the polygon at the webserver side in an XML file.

What are the ways to do that. What technology should I use. Please provide some tips or any samples or any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use WebGL.  You can display video on a canvas and draw on the canvas at the same time.    Take a look at [this experiment](http://people.mozilla.org/~rmilewski/AirMoStudio/) in video switching and compositing.   (There's a link to the GitHub source repository on the "About" tab).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try it out and post the result.